# How to redirect to given GET request url in ajax with custom header?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

This is my ajax code.

```
function regCall(token){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    dataType: 'HTML',
    headers: {
     'x-auth': token
  }
 });
}
```

Edit:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'http://localhost:3000/login/users',
    data: {
      email: $('#email').val(),
      password: $('#password').val()
    },
    success: function(data, status, req){
      localStorage.setItem('t',req.getResponseHeader('x-auth'));
      var token = localStorage.getItem('t');
      regCall(token);
    }
  });
```

I want to redirect to given url with header x-auth value as token.

Comment: Can you specify what "given url" is please?

Comment: I think to do what you are requesting you must use cache memory for store your token, then your web server should look for the x-auth header in the cache memory instead of the http header.

Comment: @BrankVictoria Sir please check the post I have edited with whole code snippet.

Comment: I want to redirect to http://localhost:3000 with given token please help.

Comment: Hello mahesh, I understand that you will go to success in the case that the authentication is OK, in that case once you have stored your token then you can just redirect the window using "window.location = URL"

Comment: In your case would be window.location = "localhost:3000"

Comment: After doing this there is an error with HTTP ERROR 400.